# multiple data with multiple groups in crystal report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I would like to best describe my problem with a simple graphical representation because I may not convey my question very well.

I have a stored procedure that contains data like this

```
 96052801 1.96 1.95 1.96 1.95 1.96
 96052801 1.96 1.95 1.96 1.95 1.96
```

The 1st data is called the header, while the numbers are different data from a table. If I have this query

```
select a as header,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e where goal = @goal
```

where goal could be something like this

```
select a as header,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e where goal = 'mem'
```

which may then output the data I illustrated earlier.

I would like to ask, how could i present in crystal reports data like this

---

```
1007576 |1007577
-----------------
1.780   |1.780
1.785   |1.786
1.790   |1.780
1.791   |1.785
1.772   |1.785
1.771   |1.786
1.770   |1.772
1.775   |1.788
1.785   |1.790
1.790   |1.778
1.786   |1.800
1.780   |1.800
1.772   |1.770
1.775   |1.775
1.780   |1.800
```

PS. Please do not mind if the data is not equal, I really names the columns as header,1,2,3,4,..

I forgot to mention the things I did before posting this question.

What I did:

I created a nested group, and put it in details section. and I have currently succeeded in presenting data like this

```
  1007576   |
    ---------
    1.780   |
    1.785   |
    1.790   |
    1.791   |
    1.772   |
    1.771   |
    1.770   |
    1.775   |
    1.785   |
    1.790   |
    1.786   |
    1.780   |
    1.772   |
    1.775   |
    1.780   |
```

However, as you may know, the other data involved is presented in another page.

Comment: In Detail section expert there is option "Format with multiple column"  after selecting layout tab appear define detail size  and select Printing direction Down and across

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it is not working. What I would want is, when new header group is found, then create a column for that another group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Mahendra suggestion make sure you set a value for width (should be wide enough to fit the value in header and the desired horizontal and vertical gaps. If you leave those as defaults then it will not use the multiple columns.

[image]

your layout would look something like below. I am using different fields than you  of course and I have only placed 3 for an example

[image]

You will need to tweak your page layout for a width you desire..

Comment: When you I set the width, the details section went to 1 inch size, I cannot replicate your screenshot above,

Comment: Marked this as a answer because setting to multiple columns would create my desired output, sadly, i could not replicate the last screenshot.